# creating an ftp server

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I am trying to create a ftp server in c#.
This server should listen to any ftp requests, and if a file is sent from a remote location, then the server should write it to a specific folder.
I am using VS2008. Do I need a tcp listener? FtpWebRequest? FtpWebResponse?

Comment: Can I ask why you would bother?  Reinventing the wheel is generally a waste of time, and there are a ton of FTP servers out there you could be using.  I can't imagine a worse way to spend my development time than on something that exists, free of charge, and has been field tested for years.

Comment: I agree, this is kinda "reinventing the wheel" but this is what I need at the moment. I need a full information of user(s), ip(s), successfully and failed attempts, file informations, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a TcpListener would be easiest to work with

There's an old article on it here that should still be usefull: [codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/sockets/article.php/c7409/)

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if writing your own FTP server is the way to go here.

Wouldn't it be easier to install a pre-rolled FTP server, and have a job that polls your FTP upload directory?  This job will identify incoming files and then places them where you need based on a set of predefined rules.

Comment: Thanks.
Yes, this is the easier solution, but I'd prefere to have my own ftp listener. I need to log all the traffic, so using other third-party app's log would be unprofessional.

Comment: Oh yeah, it is unprofessional to use existing apps, cause no ftp server out there implements some logging mechanism. It's much easier to write a complete new ftp server then a program that transform the logfile of a good running ftp server into the format i like to.

Comment: Oliver, I asked about .net technologies that could help me in building that ftp server. I don't want to parse log files and make my own logs. lol

Answer (score 2):

Can't you extend IIS ftp service?
For example: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/673/how-to-use-managed-code-c-to-create-an-ftp-authentication-provider-with-dynamic-ip-restrictions/

Or as you asked: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/579/advanced-logging-for-iis-70---custom-logging/

Comment: No, I don't have access to IIS. It is disabled by customer. Thanks for the idea anyway.