# Creating a custom FTP Server in .NET?

Tags: .net, iis, networking, ftp, extensibility

Suppose I want to create a "custom" FTP server, that is:

- It will look like a standard FTP server to the outside world
- It will actually serve data from either in-memory streams of data (dynamically generated by code) or from network streams, instead of from the actual file system

Is there an existing FTP server implementation that I can extend using .NET to accomplish the above goals? (I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922041/creating-an-ftp-server) and these [IIS extensibility points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd692904(v=VS.90).aspx) but did not find anything useful for my scenario, except for [this sample](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/sockets/article.php/c7409/) which is really close to what I want, but it looks like the project isn't being maintained and the licensing is unclear).

Comment: FTP/FTPS server component for .NET will become part of our SecureBlackbox version 8.2, which is planned for December. Beta version will be available in November (I hope so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, there *are* existing C# FTP server implementations you can use.**

Visit http://codeplex.com and search for 'ftp' (or better, 'ftp server') :)

Most are clients, but there are some (minimal) FTP/TFTP server projects there as well. YMMV.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks - this is definitely a starting point, though I was hoping for a recommendation of a project that people have some personal experience with, and that lends itself especially well to extending it in the way that I described.

Comment: I do not. Good luck and happy coding :-)